# Return data from stored procedure that contains multiple queries in EF6/MVC5

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

If I have a stored procedure with multiple queries called using different “actions” it seems like EF can’t find all the queries and make a complex type that reflects them.  It looks like it just took the first query it found in the sproc and created the result type to fit that which only includes 3 fields.

```
@Action VARCHAR(20) = Null,
@ID INT = Null,
@Username VARCHAR(50) = Null,
@Description VARCHAR(200) = Null,
@Account VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
@BranchCode SMALLINT = NULL,
@Receipt BIT = NULL,
@BackDate DATETIME = NULL,
@GetDate DATETIME = NULL,
@AccountID CHAR(16) = NULL,
@StatementDate DATETIME = NULL
as

Set @GetDate = Convert(Datetime,Convert(Varchar(10), GetDate(), 101))

IF @Action = 'GetStatements'
BEGIN
   SELECT DISTINCT [AccountID], [CardHolderName], [StatementDate]
   FROM CorpCardTransactions
   WHERE username = @username + '@xxxxxxxx.com'
   ORDER BY StatementDate
END

IF @Action = 'EmpSubmitTransactions'
BEGIN
   UPDATE CorpCardTransactions
   SET [Description] = @Description, [GL_Account] = @Account, BranchCode = @BranchCode, Receipt = @Receipt,
       SubmitDate = @GetDate
   WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

In my code I’m calling the EmpSubmitTransactions query when the “finishBtn” is clicked.

```
[HttpPost]
    public  ActionResult Index(List<CorpCardTransaction> list, string saveBtn, string finishBtn)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (saveBtn != null)
            {
                using (db)
                {
                    foreach (var i in list)
                    {
                        var t = db.CorpCardTransactions.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(i.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (t != null)
                        {
                            t.Description = i.Description;
                            t.GL_Account = i.GL_Account;
                            t.BranchCode = i.BranchCode;
                            t.Receipt = i.Receipt;
                        }
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Successfully updated.";
                    return View(list);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                using (db)
                {
                    foreach (var i in list)
                    {
                        db.sp_CorpCardExpense("EmpSubmitTransactions", i.ID, null, i.Description, i.GL_Account, i.BranchCode, i.Receipt, null, null, null, null);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Statements");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Ooops, something is wrong with the Model State.  Try again.";
            return View(list);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the finishBtn, it does get to the right part of the code and it does try and fire off the stored procedure, but it gives me this error,

“The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CorpCardTransactionsModel.sp_CorpCardExpense_Result'. A member of the type, 'AccountID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.”

I’m not trying to return all the fields, I’m just trying to send them all to the sproc plus let the sproc do some other things like mark the fields as “finished” then redirect me to the list of statements again.  I’m only updating the table, not returning any fields, and trying to redirect so I guess I don’t understand why it can’t find “AccountID”.    Why is it referring to a data reader?

Comment: Why in the world don't you make two different stored procedures, instead of having a single procedure that does two completely different things depending on a string input? It's a horrific design in my honest opinion.

Comment: We thought that by using @action we could just throw all of our queries into one sproc per project.  Worked great in WebForms using datatables, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this to work well in EF.  Is it more correct to create a new sproc for every query?  For this particular project I'd have 8 different stored procedures.  That doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Is that the answer?  You all agree that you should have separate stored procedure for each query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up breaking out all queries into individual stored procedures.  This let me add each new one to my model when I choose to update from database.  It automatically setup complex types for ones that returned values and didn't for those that had no data to return (updates, etc).

Worked great.  Thanks for the suggestion.